# How to get reference to inserted object from std::map::emplace()?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

How to get reference to inserted object from `std::map::emplace()`?
Official doc for [emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace).
I have added `auto inserted = m.emplace("d", "ddd");`

**Can you please demonstrate how to get reference to just inserted `"ddd"`?**

I receive some ridiculous type `struct std::_Rb_tree_iterator` and cannot find any documentation or example how to work with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

#include <map>
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m;

    // uses pair's template constructor
    auto inserted = m.emplace("d", "ddd");

    for (const auto &p : m) {
        std::cout << p.first << " => " << p.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the emplace fails? What would your reference refer to?

Comment: @juanchopanza offtopic. You can do the presence check with `find()` and then compare that returned iterator points to `end()`

Comment: Yes, but a reference has to refer to a valid object. Which is why `emplace` gives you an iterator, which doesn't have to refer to a valid object, and a bool, which tells you if the emplace succeeded. I'm not really sure what you're having problems with.

Comment: @juanchopanza can you please demonstrate how to get `std::string&` to just inserted `"ddd"`? It is obviously present in the map.

Comment: I could, but I am not sure which part you're having trouble with. To me, it seems pretty clear from the documentation you linked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`map.emplace` return a pair containing an iterator to object and a boolean (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/emplace/)

and the iterator for map is a kind of pointer to a pair of key and value. So, you can do :

```
auto inserted = m.emplace("d", "ddd");
if (inserted.second == true)
{
    auto &ref_to_ddd = inserted.first->second;
}
```